# Read data from Mitutoyo gauge

Tags: serial-port, serial-communication, communication-protocol, tcomport

I need to write a program that will read the data from the indicator once a minute. Unfortunately, I can not find the communication protocol for this indicator (the official representative responds extremely unqualified and there is no way to get at least some information from him). Some programmer (with whom I do not have a connection) wrote a similar program earlier, but did not leave the source code. In the Device Manager on computer the indicator is defined as USB-ITN. I will be grateful for any information in solving this problem.

**Indicator model: *ID-U1025M*
Indicator Serial Number: *13063340*
USB cable: *ITN - 60010409***

[image: Mitutoyo model:ID-U1025M]

Comment: hi, did you manage to read the gauge ?

Comment: Hello, yes i did.

Comment: thanks, can you post the directions (or solution) ?

Comment: I did decompilation for some software project and got the communication protocol. You can download my project here: https://github.com/osipov1980/HuberTest   Also You need driver for Mitutoyo USB-ITN cable. I did not find some driver and just cut this with Double Driver software from PC ;)) I put them inside the folder with my project, so You can restore the driver on your PC.

Comment: many thanks, I'll checkout

Answer (score 0):

You should ask the nearby Mitutoyo branch. 
[Mitutoyo Worldwide](http://www.mitutoyo.co.jp/global.html)

The published information of the product you are using seems to be the following.
[Japanese version document for ID-U1025](http://www.mitutoyo.co.jp/useful/catalog-13-48/index.html#page=361)
[English version document for similar product](http://www.mitutoyo.co.jp/eng/useful/catalog-2016/index.html#page=355)

A description of the tool and data format will be as follows.
[USB Input Tool Direct/Input Tool SERIES](http://www.mitutoyo.co.jp/eng/useful/catalog-2016/index.html#page=33)
[U-WAVE](http://www.mitutoyo.co.jp/eng/useful/catalog-2016/index.html#page=35)
[U-WAVE/Common Optional Software](http://www.mitutoyo.co.jp/eng/useful/catalog-2016/index.html#page=37)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to communicate by using the driver bundled in the software [USB-ITPAK](https://shop.mitutoyo.eu/web/mitutoyo/en/mitutoyo/1358923788887/USB-ITPAK/index.xhtml)
. The thing is, that the driver installation is not straightforward at all. use the USB-ITPAK User's Manual(English) to get the instructions (Section 2.3 Installing the VCP Driver). One needs to follow the instructions to the letter - which refer to detecting the device in the device manager and installing the driver **to each device** - even if it is the same device!

Once the driver is installed properly - the connection will behave like a serial port - send the character 1 to get the measurement returned (for detailed communication command specification - check section 9.2).